# boot full and cannot clean

Tags: 14.04, boot, cleanup

I reviewed the "Can't clean a full /boot because of unmet dependencies" and it cleared the boot to about 43% used on boot.
Then I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and it put all of the `linux-images` back and I was full again with same problem.  It looks like I'll have to backup my documents and do a complete install or use the clone-zilla image from two years ago.

I see that there a lots of problems with boot space. I have several linux computers with 14.04 and my major problem is with boot always being full.  Is there a fix and a suggest process to fix this.  It takes lots of my time?

Comment: Is your /boot partition is out of free space ? If so try removing older kernel images.

Comment: Here is the similar thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/585736/cant-clean-a-full-boot-because-of-unmet-dependencies check that whether this helps

Comment: See [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels) for help in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tool that automates this chore, in case it helps anyone else: https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem. It removes unused kernel and kernel header packages, and is intended to be run periodically. If, when upgrading, you only need the currently running kernel (as a fallback) plus the latest available kernel, this tool might be for you.

Comment: You may add a bit more description what does your script exactly, and how to use it. Think about that not everyone is maybe as savvy as you. It also would enhance the quality of your answer.