# Deleted old kernels, but boot partition still full

Tags: boot, kernel, disk

I'm a Ubuntu noob, so bear with me here.
I have a Ubuntu server (16.04.6) that I use for Plex and NAS, and my Webmin dashboard told me that my boot partition was full. I removed all the old kernels, but it still says 0 available space. Google has been to no help. I saw other people here having similar problems, but the solutions didn't help me, so I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Edit: I'm guessing old kernels aren't my problem, but I don't understand what could fill my entire boot partition like this. More importantly, what can I delete from the partition without messing something up?

Output from `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9.2M  780M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  229G  226G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0        3.7T  2.0T  1.7T  54% /mnt/Media
tmpfs           789M     0  789M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Output from `sudo dpkg --list | egrep -i 'linux-image'`:

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-184-generic         4.4.0-184.214                                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-189-generic         4.4.0-189.219                                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic   4.4.0-142.168                                   i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                   4.4.0.189.195                                   i386         Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Remove old Kernels from Full Boot Disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741981/cannot-remove-old-kernels-from-full-boot-disk)

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, but it did clean up the output from <sudo dpkg --list | egrep -i 'linux-image'> :). Edited my first post to show this.

Comment: Total size of `/var/log/` is only 17M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong!
A couple of days ago, I was playing around with scheduled back-ups in Webmin. I started backing up some data from my server to a USB drive just to see if it worked. Everything worked fine, so I scheduled a complete back-up for the next day. When I checked to see if the back-up had completed, I saw that it hadn't. There was an error message, but I couldn't make sense of it and thought I'd just try doing the backup again another day.

Now I realise that (noob alert!) I had forgot to mount the USB drive on day 2, so when Webmin tried to do what I had asked and couldn't find the destination folder, it apparently just created it in the mount point for my now absent USB drive and started copying until my boot drive ran out of space. When I eventually noticed that the USB drive wasn't mounted, I didn't connect the dots, so I just mounted it normally. As the mount point now contained a huge back-up file that had filled up my boot drive, mounting my USB drive made it invisible. No wonder I couldn't find it :D ! By chance, I just tried searching for large files on the server while the USB drive was disconnected, and there it was! I deleted it, and the problem was solved.