# How to fix full boot partition with unmet dependencies

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dependencies

My Ubuntu instance will do security updates until boot partition is full and from then on kernel updates will fail.

When boot is full it is also not possible to remove older kernels because there are unmet dependencies. Apt will not allow those unmet dependencies to exist. As shown below, I cannot purge 138 because of unmet dependencies but I also cannot install 138 because the disk is full.

I suppose at this point I have edit dependencies manually. Bypassing Apt. How can I fix this issue? Without completely reinstalling Ubuntu?

```
[user@mysystem:~] $ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried the suggestion in [Can't clean a full /boot because of unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585736/cant-clean-a-full-boot-because-of-unmet-dependencies). I used commands like

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

This does free up space. But if I run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -f
```

Those kernels will be downloaded and installed again. Untill `boot` is again full. So `autoremove` and `purge` in the last command is a bit misleading to say the least.

At this point I think the only way to really fix this is to increase `boot` partition. It seems small with only given the way that Ubuntu updates kernels. It should be a lot larger default size with ample warnings.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: I don't think that wil work. Apt is determined to first install and then purge. Not the other way around. IMHO it would be better to purge first and install after but that is not how Apt does it.

Comment: They key was maintenance (keep boot clean so it doesn't occur), but if you look further it also covered removing old kernels including when you have broken deps due to space issues.

Comment: Which kernel version are you running (`uname -r`)? Which kernel versions are kept in `/boot` and which are going to be installed by APT? What’s your `/boot` partition size?